# What is the voltage at feeding end?

Tags: power-supply

I am currently studying "Principles of Power System by V. K. Mehta". I am stuck at a tutorial problem from chapter 13, which is as follows:

> A 2-wire d.c. distributor, 500 m long is fed at one of its ends. The cross-sectional area of each conductor is 3·4 cm² and the resistivity of copper is 1·7 μΩcm. The distributor supplies 200 A at a distance of 300m from the feeding point and 100 A at the terminus. Calculate the voltage at the feeding end if the
>   voltage at the terminus is to be 230 V.

Here is my solution:

[image: handwritten solution attempt]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the voltage at the feeding end?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356910/what-is-the-voltage-at-the-feeding-end)

Comment: He has deleted it.

Comment: @SamGibson: nice crop and contrast enhancement. Why didn't OP do this?

Comment: Note the possible ambiguity or misreading in the question  I read it as supplying 200A TO point C alone, PLUS 100A to point B.

Answer (score 2):

Work backwards:

Section C-B

- You know what \$ V_B \$ and \$ I_B \$ are so you can work out what voltage is required at C to get that.

Section A-C

- Now you know \$ V_C \$ and \$ I_A \$ so you can work out what voltage is required at A.

Comment: That is a really good example of an answer - that leads the OP further! neat.